# npm installs packages and dependencies in the project root directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I switched from Windows to Mac. When I'm trying to install npm modules, the packages and their dependencies are created inside the project root directory.

On Windows the module was installing into ./node_modules, with all dependencies inside module folder.

Is there something I need to configure to make it work as before?

**edit**

I have both, node_modules folder and package.json in my project dir:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "chokidar": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

And still, chokidar package and its dependencies are in the project root.

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35227212/4063622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `npm install`, it will get up until it finds a package.json or a node_modules folder and install your package there.

So if your project structure is like this

```
project_root/
  modules/
    mymodule/
  node_modules
```

And you run `npm install` in mymod directory, the module will be installed in project_root/node_modules

Comment: I have both, and it's still the same. Please see the edit.

Comment: Bit late to the party here but if you do `npm init -y` then it will create a package.json file in the directory you are currently in so that when you do `npm install` this will be in ./node_modules