# "npm install" installs all dependencies in node_modules directory, instead of having them nested

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I need to know if the following behavior is normal.

When I `npm install`, each package from my **package.json** and the dependencies, don't get installed **nested** anymore, but each dependency is installed in the `node_modules` directory. That makes my `node_modules` directory blown and look like this:

[image: Screenshot of node_modules directory]

This happened since I updated npm and node.

Now I run:

```
npm -v 3.3.6
node -v 4.2.1
python 2.7
windows 7
wamp
```

My `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

It's the standard laravel `package.json` file.

Is there a way to have nested directories again, because I don't like such a blown article with over 100 sub directories.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's the **new** behavior of `npm 3` as per [this npm blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5).

Comment: Thanks sagie, I guess there is no way to make it nested again to avoid a bloated directory, is there? (Also have to wait 5 min, before being able to accept your answer as the correct one)

Comment: Flat is better as I see it. As a windows user, it is really horrible to delete too much nested modules as it passes the 256 max charaters really fast (or was it 1024,can't remember). Also i helps when you upgrade modules as now it is able to better reuse existing installations and not replace everything under the module you upgraded as maybe its dependencies didn't change. bottom line, its much faster and cleaner this way.

Comment: I kept trying to troubleshoot NPM lol...glad I ran across this or I would still be hunting for a solution =)

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness In fact, there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 61):

**Update:** As Erik Pukinskis mentioned in the comments: 
As of npm 3.5, support for `--legacy-bundling` has been dropped.

---

Yes, there is a way to have nested directories again by changing npm's (version 3 as of this writing) default behaviour:

1. Delete the currently present `node_modules` folder.
2. Tell npm to install with legacy bundling for this one install:

   `npm install --legacy-bundling`

A "permanent" alternative:

2. Set your npm config to always use legacy bundling...

   `npm set legacy-bundling=true`
3. .. and run as usual:

   `npm install`

**Note:** fetching dependencies with legacy bundling will take a lot more time because many several different versions of the same dependencies will be installed.

**Disclaimer:** As a non-Windows user I have no need for flat dependencies and want to find self-declared dependencies with ease in favour of automatic deduping. Since installing npm dependencies without legacy bundling already takes an incredible amount of time I'm usually willing to spend those extra minutes install time. It gets back down to 5 directories from previously 700+ (...) in a Laravel Elixir setup with bootstrap (non-sass), font-awesome and jquery added.

Comment: This answer was highly useful to me for my specific case. Describing here for posterity: I have been trying to build package.json with dependencies for an existing node project. using `npm install <list of packages I require> --legacy-bundling --save` wrote only the direct dependencies into package.json. I then did `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`, to get back the new flat node_modules directory. This is the best of both worlds for me.

Comment: I also consider this the correct answer, as it directly answers OP in the affirmative

Comment: As of npm 3.5, support for `--legacy-bundling` has been dropped.

Comment: I can this option it in npm docs and github repository https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/e09bdc142a4d9fe247927eb82a49720d5370b293/docs/content/using-npm/config.md