# Have NPM put dependencies inside dependencies when running "npm install"?

Tags: json, node.js, npm

So I have a package.json that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "node-api",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

When I run "npm install" on Ubuntu I get a tree structure in node_modules that looks like this:

```
.
├── body-parser
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── types
│   └── node_modules
│       ├── bytes
│       ├── content-type
│       ├── debug
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── depd
│       │   └── lib
│       ├── http-errors
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── iconv-lite
│       │   ├── encodings
│       │   └── lib
│       ├── on-finished
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── qs
│       │   ├── dist
│       │   ├── lib
│       │   └── test
│       ├── raw-body
│       │   └── node_modules
│       └── type-is
│           └── node_modules
├── express
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── middleware
│   │   └── router
│   └── node_modules
│       ├── accepts
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── array-flatten
│       ├── content-disposition
│       ├── content-type
│       ├── cookie
│       ├── cookie-signature
│       ├── debug
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── depd
│       │   └── lib
│       ├── escape-html
│       ├── etag
│       ├── finalhandler
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── fresh
│       ├── merge-descriptors
│       ├── methods
│       ├── on-finished
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── parseurl
│       ├── path-to-regexp
│       ├── proxy-addr
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── qs
│       │   ├── lib
│       │   └── test
│       ├── range-parser
│       ├── send
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── serve-static
│       ├── type-is
│       │   └── node_modules
│       ├── utils-merge
│       └── vary
└── mongoose
    ├── examples
    │   ├── aggregate
    │   ├── express
    │   │   └── connection-sharing
    │   ├── geospatial
    │   ├── globalschemas
    │   ├── lean
    │   ├── mapreduce
    │   ├── population
    │   ├── promises
    │   ├── querybuilder
    │   ├── replicasets
    │   ├── schema
    │   │   └── storing-schemas-as-json
    │   └── statics
    ├── lib
    │   ├── drivers
    │   │   ├── browser
    │   │   └── node-mongodb-native
    │   ├── error
    │   ├── schema
    │   ├── services
    │   └── types
    └── node_modules
        ├── async
        │   └── lib
        ├── bson
        │   ├── alternate_parsers
        │   ├── browser_build
        │   ├── lib
        │   └── tools
        ├── hooks-fixed
        ├── kareem
        │   └── test
        ├── mongodb
        │   ├── lib
        │   ├── node_modules
        │   └── test_boot
        ├── mpath
        │   ├── lib
        │   └── test
        ├── mpromise
        │   ├── lib
        │   └── test
        ├── mquery
        │   ├── lib
        │   ├── node_modules
        │   └── test
        ├── ms
        ├── muri
        │   ├── lib
        │   └── test
        ├── regexp-clone
        │   └── test
        └── sliced
            ├── lib
            └── test
```

123 directories
I only am showing 4 levels deep of the directory tree but the top level are just the 3 "dependencies" in my packages.json.  I like this because it keeps everything nice and organized.

Here is how it shows up on my Mac:

```
.
├── accepts
├── array-flatten
├── async
├── bluebird
├── body-parser
├── bson
├── bytes
├── content-disposition
├── content-type
├── cookie
├── cookie-signature
├── core-util-is
├── debug
├── depd
├── destroy
├── ee-first
├── es6-promise
├── escape-html
├── etag
├── express
├── finalhandler
├── forwarded
├── fresh
├── hooks-fixed
├── http-errors
├── iconv-lite
├── inherits
├── ipaddr.js
├── isarray
├── kareem
├── media-typer
├── merge-descriptors
├── methods
├── mime
├── mime-db
├── mime-types
├── mongodb
├── mongodb-core
├── mongoose
├── mpath
├── mpromise
├── mquery
├── ms
├── muri
├── negotiator
├── on-finished
├── parseurl
├── path-to-regexp
├── proxy-addr
├── qs
├── range-parser
├── raw-body
├── readable-stream
├── regexp-clone
├── send
├── serve-static
├── sliced
├── statuses
├── string_decoder
├── type-is
├── unpipe
├── utils-merge
└── vary
```

I personally hate that because you can't tell why a certain dependency is there if your project gets big, and it can get messy real fast.

Both computers are running npm 2.14.7 and node 4.2.2.  Is there any way to make it store dependencies in the structure of the first tree that I showed?

Comment: Are you sure that the last one was installed with npm 2.x.x? That would be the expected behaviour for npm 3.x.x as [sated here](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0), with all the dependencies under one folder.

Comment: As @JAntunes mentioned - that's npm 3's default behaviour. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35227212/580651) on how to revert to the former directory tree.