# NPM install package without nested node_modules

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am running into the Windows Path character limit.

When I run an install of 'gulp' for example, via

> npm install --save-dev gulp

in a folder such as "C:\Users\MyUsername\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject", I find that all the dependencies are deeply nested, such as:

> C:\Users\MyUsername\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MyProject\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\loud-rejection\node_modules\signal-exit

Is there a way to avoid this?  How do other Windows developers get past this?

Comment: There's a way to avoid this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35227212/580651

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a NPM version 3.x.
According to this [Node npm windows file paths are too long to install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155135/node-npm-windows-file-paths-are-too-long-to-install-packages) most problems with nesting is solved in version 3.x

Comment: You are correct, even with a brand new installation of node.js, NPM was still at version 2.x.  I updated it, and it works now!  I will accept your answer shortly!