# Submodule's dependency is missing in webpack build

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, webpack

This might be a stupid question, but somehow I can't get to find a solution for it.

I created a nodejs library with utilities that I use in many projects, let's say it's called `foo`. This library use modules that are declared in it's package.json, like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "utf8": "^2.1.2"
  },
```

Then I have an ionic3 app (let's say it's called `bar`) in which I want to use this library, so in `bar`'s `package.json`, I declare: `"foo": "../foo",`

The problem, is that when I try to open my app in the browser, I get the following message:

```
  Error: Cannot find module "utf8" someScriptLocatedInFoo.js:1:26
    webpackMissingModule someScriptLocatedInFoo.js:1
    1259                 someScriptLocatedInFoo.js:1
    Bootstrap11Webpack
```

I don't get any error message for jquery, moment, or underscore because they are declared in `bar`'s package.json. This makes me think that maybe webpack is not able, when building, to find the module `utf8` located in `node_modules/foo/node_modules/utf8`.

The only thing I can imagine to get around this problem is to install `foo`'s  dependency manually in `bar` but it doesn't make sense, I cannot expect any person that uses a library I created to install manually all the modules it depends on. Or is there a way to declare in `foo`'s `package.json` modules to ask npm to install in `bar`'s `node_modules` directory when running `npm install --save ../foo`? (without the need to manually decide to use legacy-bundling as explained in luchaos answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154836/npm-install-installs-all-dependencies-in-node-modules-directory-instead-of-ha)).

Comment: And what's your `webpack` config? It seems like you're excluding `foo` from bundling.

Comment: @sarneeh I don't have any custom webpack config, it's the default one from ionic (this is how it looks like: https://pastebin.com/LjQ6m2Nj), if I'm not mistaken and it's the one located in `node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js`.